# Python-Pandas ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am running the following code python-pandas code:

```
try:
   result1 = getFunction() 
   if result1["NumberOfPeople"]=="Not found":
                    breaK
                
except:
    raise
```

result1 is a dataframe that contains 2 columns: Name and NumberOfPeople

The error i'm getting is:
**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Any help?

Comment: with this condition: `if result1["NumberOfPeople"]=="Not found":` what are you really trying to check? Whether the entire column contains the same value (`"Not found"`)? Or something else?

Comment: What kind of an object is result1?  If it is a pandas DataFrame or pandas Series, then you need to add `.all()` or `.any()`.  Reason is that what if part of you series is 'Not found' and other parts has something else.

Comment: @KirtimanSinha i want to check if at least one row has "not found" in numberOfPeople column.

once this condition is found, i want my code to break

Comment: Use  `if (result1["NumberOfPeople"]== "Not found").any():`  if any row in result1 has 'Not found' then break.

Comment: Thank you @ScottBoston. It works :)

Answer (score 1):

`if result1["NumberOfPeople"]` will return `.series`, must cast to `.str`

```
try:
   result1 = getFunction() 
   if result1["NumberOfPeople"].astype(str)=="Not found": #change from series to string
                    break        
except:
    raise
```

Comment: @ScottBoston The user who asked the question use `pandas` tag, in pandas this will return series ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)).

Comment: Right.... But you can not take a pd.Series and check to like this s == "value" it will always ValueError: The truth value of Series is ambigious. Because, part so the series maybe True other parts False.  Casting as a string doessn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`result1["NumberOfPeople"]` is a series (the whole column). When you compare a series with a string you get a series of booleans where each value is compared to the string. So `result1["NumberOfPeople"]=="Not found"` is a pandas series, which can't be casted to a string.

Perphaps you want to iterate over your dataframe rows, in such case you should use [iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows)

So your code would be something like

```
result1 = getFunction() 
for row in result1.iterrows():
    if row["NumberOfPeople"] == "Not found":
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
try:
   result1 = getFunction() 
   if result1["NumberOfPeople"].str.contains("Not found", regex=False):
       break
                
except:
    raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `any` to check to see if any records in your pandas Series equals to 'Not found'.

```
if (result1["NumberOfPeople"]== "Not found").any():
```

This will avoid the ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.